# Regex match validation for less than n or n times

Tags: regex, bash, xsd, ksh, xsd-validation

Suppose I have regex as below : [a-z]{1,28}

This will match the below string as per two matches given below:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Match 1
Full match  0-28    `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab`

Match 2
Full match  28-52   `cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

I want to match only 28 or less than 28 characters on that.That means if my string is greater than 28 character,my validation should fail.

Please advise on the above.The problem I am facing is in when I am defining this validation xsd pattern(xs:pattern value="[a-z]{1,28}")

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you need to match the whole string? Add anchors - `^[a-z]{1,28}$`

Comment: there are no anchors as such,only charcters like a-z or A-Z or there can be 12345 in square brackets also

Comment: Anchors are `^` (start of string/line) and `$` (end of string/line).

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries `\b` to denote the needed sequence:

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" | egrep '\b[a-z]{1,28}\b'
# won't find the matches
```

---

```
echo "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab abc" | egrep -o '\b[a-z]{1,28}\b'
```

Outputs:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab 
abc
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this,this is working for me in unix but when I am using this in pattern of xsd file,it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

match with beginning/end of string.

```
str="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

# Your solution.
if [[ $str =~ [a-z]{1,28} ]]; then
   echo "First match"
fi
# Solution `matching complete line
if [[ $str =~ ^[a-z]{1,28}$ ]]; then
   echo "Second match"
fi
```